# Can you reverse a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, reverse

I'm interested in reversing a string in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7):

PostgreSQL 9.1 and later includes a built-in function

```
 reverse(text)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 2):

Here you have reversing string function for PostreSQL:

http://a-kretschmer.de/diverses.shtml

Answer (score -1):

You can use [reverse()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) as shown below:

```sql
SELECT reverse('hello'); -- olleh
```

Comment: This answer was already given 12 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281992/73226